# Problem compiling subgraph with graph-ts new version

Tags: compilation, data-types, graphs, the-graph

I'm getting this error: `ERROR TS2322: Type '~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/value/Value | null' is not assignable to type '~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/value/Value'.`

I know it is for this change they made (https://thegraph.com/docs/developer/assemblyscript-migration-guide#nullability-check-with-property-access) but I don't know how to refactor the code to make it work. This is the code I have that gives the error:

```
  save(): void {
    let id = this.get("id");
    assert(id !== null, "Cannot save Bundle entity without an ID");
    assert(
      id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
      "Cannot save Bundle entity with non-string ID. " +
        'Considering using .toHex() to convert the "id" to a string.'
    );
    store.set("Bundle", id.toString(), this);
  }
```

The specific line is this one:

```
id.kind == ValueKind.STRING,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 ways to solve this:

1. in your schema.graphql set kind as optional with a ! at the end

```
kind: Value!
```

2. you check for yor variable ValueKind.STRING to be not null

```
  if(null!===ValueKind.STRING)
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that you shared is from `generated/schema.ts` ?

Hard to say, but the error looks like a type conversion problem.
Would need to see your full handler code to give an exact answer, but you can try to use a type cast like `as Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Graph CLI with either npm or yarn. Copy into your terminal:

```
npm install -g @graphprotocol/graph-cli
```

or

```
yarn global add @graphprotocol/graph-cli
```

and make sure you are having typescript version > 2.1

Comment: This is almost certainly not the problem Matias is facing.